# How to make a slideshow with collection field?

Tags: entities, views

I have a content type called Building. These buildings have many planes with its own name.
In my content type, I have a collection Field (unlimited values) whose sub-fields:

- Image
- Title

I'm trying to make a slider with the sub-field image, making the titles of the images as a pager.
I created a Block-View which receives the nid as argument from the URL.

I have the Field Slideshow module for the Formatter Slideshow in views module.
My current configuration is:

- Formatter: Slideshow
- Image Field: Field Collection field:image
- Multiple field setting - Display all values in the same row: YES
- CONTEXTUAL FILTERS - Content: Nid - Content ID from URL

This configuration makes the images function as slider. But, I don't know how putting all titles of the images as a pager.